# Tomcat 5.5/Liferay - unable to make JDBC connection after upgrade

Tags: tomcat, liferay

Been stuck on this one for a couple days now...I have an existing Liferay 4.4.0 portal running fine on Tomcat 5.5.28. I need to update to at least tomcat 5.5.30 (or ideally, 5.5.35) to apply [this patch](https://issues.apache.org/bugzilla/show_bug.cgi?id=48843).

No matter how many different ways I try it (starting from the tomcat 5.5 download and adding in liferay, or updating a copy of my existing (working) tomcat setup with the updated tomcat jars), I get stuck at the same point at startup (Linux, RHEL):

```
Starting Liferay Enterprise Portal 4.4.0 (Spurgeon / Build 4400 /
January 25, 2008) Cannot create JDBC driver of class '' for connect
URL 'null' java.lang.NullPointerException
         at sun.jdbc.odbc.JdbcOdbcDriver.getProtocol(JdbcOdbcDriver.java:507)
```

(etc)

Just like my working site, I have the mysql connector jar in /common/lib, and have my database connection setup the same in /conf/Catalina/localhost/ROOT.xml

Things I've noticed:

- Removing ROOT.xml causes the same exact error, so it looks like it's never even reading this file
- When I go the route of updating via copying the tomcat jars over to an existing "good" installation, it works up until I copy over the jars from /server/lib, whereas I get that same error message.

Any help is much appreciated, I'm pulling my hair out at this point!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, I got this to work via the solution provided in [Cannot create JDBC driver of class '' for connect URL 'null'](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7274722/cannot-create-jdbc-driver-of-class-for-connect-url-null) , by putting in my jdbc connection information in /conf/context.xml

Seems like a band-aid more than a solution, but it does work.